# Concurrent but synchronous GRPC server call handling

Tags: c#, grpc

When multiple clients concurrently make the same call to a GRPC server, does the server answer these calls asynchronously? In case I want the server to handle the calls synchronously should I use some sort of locking like `AsyncSemaphore`? Using this pattern, how long can I "hold" an ongoing call (e.g. two clients make the same call at the same time, one blocks until the call of the first client has been answered) until GRPC cancels it or the client drops the connection? Does GRPC have critical timeouts in this regard?

Comment: Did you implement the GRPC server? Is it someone else's code? What language / platform is it running on?

Comment: It's my code, the language is C#

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did it answer them asychronously?

Comment: I'd like to avoid the try and guess approach. I guess the server handles the calls concurrently. However, this doesn't answer my question regarding timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC will answer calls asynchronously.  If you want a server to service only a single call, you should use a lock in your handler.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: you should accept calls concurrently (nothing to be done here, that's the default behavior) and implement the synchronization logic in you handlers - it doesn't necessarily have to be a lock, but you could use analogous primitives (e.g. add the request to a synchronous processing queue and await completion of the request). The in-progress calls will stay live as long as you've set a long-enough deadline on the client side.